# what to do if the OP removed content from its question?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

While reviewing, I stumbled upon [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/603052/4). The OP removed the text of his/her question, substituing it with the sentence

> Please remove this, the question has gone unanswered and help is
>   needed no longer.

I don't know which is the correct thing to do in such cases: my inner Wikipedian would restore the original text, but of course this is not Wikipedia :-)

Comment: (I hope I linked to the correct question.)

Comment: I've reverted.  The user seems to have deleted his/her account, and there's no reason to keep the non-question text.  (Generally just revert and/or flag for moderator attention. The latter mainly if a user persists in defacing a question, especially after an answer has been given.)

Comment: To add to @ArthurFischer: one should of course flag for moderator attention also in the case where one does not have editing privileges (though in that case one would not be likely to be looking at the review queues).

Comment: @WillieWong Sure, but there's also the case where if you're a lower rep user who happens to stumble upon a question that needs a rollback...

Comment: It seems to me that the situation is different depending on whether the question has an answer.  If it has an answer, the defacement should absolutely be reverted; it's too late to throw it away.  But if there are no answers yet, why not flag the question for deletion?  A higher-reputation user would have been able to summarily delete the question themselves, and had the author flagged the question for deletion by the moderators, they would have complied; isn't this so? So why not carry out the author's implied request and delete the post?